Is there a widget size limit Tkinter and/or a way to override it?
I'm not talking about maxsize(), which is the only thing that appears on Google.
I would like to know if there is a known pixel limit to a Tkinter widget, if it is for a specific widget or if it's generic for all widgets, and if there's any way to override that limit.
I'm making a Tkinter GUI app that pulls LLDP data through SSH from a large network switch, and it works as intended. (Yes, I know, .NET would be better, but I already made a Python library for most of the back end actions with this equipment for little 1-time-use scripts, so I can reuse a lot of my code this way.) The only issue is that when very large numbers of sub-frames are added (each sub frame shows data from a different connected device), there seems to be a widget size limit that cuts off the bottom parts of my list. I can confirm it's a pixel size limit and not a child limit, as when I make the sub-frames smaller, or even the padding between the sub-frames smaller, I can fit more sub-frames.
The set-up is inside the base Tk() window; there is a frame on the right half of the screen containing the scroll bar and a canvas. The canvas contains a window, which is another frame. This is to make the frame scrollable. The frame is then dynamically resized, and child frames containing the polled data polled are added to the scrollable frame.
I'm unsure if it's the window, the canvas, or the frame that reaches a height limit, but after about ~300 devices, it cuts off the bottom. If I reduce those down to 1 line of data (device name and nothing else), I can get up to ~750, by reducing padding, I can get just over 800. This defeats the purpose of the app, though, as less data is shown in the GUI and these switches have 1024 ports.
I know Tkinter is not optimized for such large things, but that's not an issue; I can do the optimizations myself.

Can you provide a [mre] so we can see what you have so far?

The canvas has a limit, so if the objects are going in the canvas (or in a widget in a canvas) there is a hard limit.

Thanks. If you know by chance what that limit is, that would be helpful. I could then append multiple canvas's into a canvas when one's max size is reached and mess with the scrolling logic to scroll through a sub-canvas, and as that is fully scrolled, scroll the parent canvas until the next sub-canvas is aligned with the parent canvas and continue.

@Mitchellhingley: you should be able to write a program that gives you the answer by just creating a large widget and putting it in a canvas. I think the answer is probably around either 32k or 64k pixels.

I don't think that will work as the canvas technically expands, as evidence that I can scroll further if I add more things, they just don't display after a certain pixel count. But thank you, I will use those estimates as a starting point and figure the rest out. Regardless, simply knowing that there is a max size is mostly what I was curious about so thank you!

@Mitchellhingley: You can measure how big a frame gets before it stops being visible. For example, create a frame with 10,000 10-pixel tall sections and count how many are visible. You can put a label in each section to tell you which number it is.
